Earliest historical work on Cauchy's infinitesimal delta functions?
As early as 1981, Hans Freudenthal briefly mentioned Cauchy's work on "singular integrals (i.e., integrals of infinitely large functions over infinitely small paths [$\delta$ functions])" on page 135 of his biography of Cauchy in the Dictionary of Scientific Biography (edited by
Gillispie).
A 1989 article by Detlef Laugwitz contains a section 5.5 starting on page 227 entitled "Cauchy and delta functions".  At bottom of page 229, Laugwitz mentions Cauchy's use of the "language of infinitesimals" (on page 289 of Note XVIII in Cauchy's publication from 1827).  This is in reference to Cauchy's infinitesimal $\alpha$ appearing in $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha^2+(\mu-a)^2}$, which integrated against $f(x)$ produces the value $f(a)$ of $f$ at the point $a$ (of course, from the modern point of view, the relation is not that of equality on the nose but rather infinite proximity).
Question 1. Freudenthal's tone in 1981 seems to suggest that he is reporting something well-known.  Which earlier historians (earlier than 1981) may have written about Cauchy's use of infinitesimals in writing down a formula for a delta-function (such as the $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha^2+(\mu-a)^2}$
above)?
This question was asked at MO.
Question 2. Actually Freudenthal wrote his biography of Cauchy sometime during the period 1970-1980 (when the Dictionary was being developed) and it appeared in volume 3 of the Dictionary.  It would be interesting to determine a more precise date when volume 3 originally appeared (the whole thing was finalized by 1981).

On question 2 I'm not sure if this is helpful, but the worldcat entry for volume 3 dates the first edition at 1971.

Laugitz (1997) dates Freudenthal's work at 1971: " The first to mention
the role of "delta functions" in the research papers of Cauchy
was Freudenthal in 1971, and Lützen in 1982 paid due credit to
Fourier, Cauchy and Poisson (1)."

Cauchy, Poisson, Hermite, Kirchhoff and Helmholtz are credited already by van der Pol-Bremmer, see p.64 of 1959 edition (the first is from 1947). Sheynin, 1975 mentions Cauchy and Poisson from there (as pointed out to him by Medvedev) and credits already Laplace. But they, Lützen and Synowiec, 1983 all phrase it as "approximations" of delta function.

@conifold Fascinating! Incidentally it is known that Freudenthal knew of van der Pol (and wrote an article about prime numbers in textiles in that regard!).

@GeorgEssl, thanks for your comments.  The year for Laugwitz's article that you linked seems to be 1992, not 1997.

@MikhailKatz Yes, on top of having mispelled his name. Apologies!

@GeorgEssl, no problem.  Notice that Lauwitz's claim that Freudenthal (1971) was the first to credit Cauchy and Poisson seems to overlook van der Pol as per Conifold's comment above.  On the other hand, Freudenthal does appear to be the first to mention Cauchy's infinitesimal delta function (with what van der Pol refers to as the "sifting" property).

@MikhailKatz The "sifting" view is rather canonical among engineers due to having an essentially trivial intuition in the case of Fourier transforms. Incidentally the google books scan seems to miss 2 pages so there may be more here. Furthermore van der Pol's comment suggest that traces of Cauchy might be discoverable in Helmholtz, Kirchhoff and other practitioners on wave problems in acoustics and electromagnetism in the later 19th century. Given van der Pol's work in EM I think that's a plausible path through which he might have learned of Cauchy's work.

@GeorgEssl, yes, there is more there, such as quotations from Poisson and Hermite explicitly mentioning infinitesimals.  Of course, van der Pol and Bremmer don't write anything about infinitesimals themselves; in the 1950s infinitesimals were still traditionally thought of as self-contradictory chimeras.  One can't expect van der Pol and Bremmer to act otherwise; whether or not one can expect this of more recent scholars is a potentially interesting question :-)
